# PHP array out of order

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I am pulling information from a database- from two different tables. The origins of the data is a single archival document- so each row from the two tables has a unique value- line number.

So the code is as follows

```
//get data about the report as a whole.
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reports_list WHERE report_key ='" . $report_key . "'";
$report_data = $wpdb->get_results ($sql);

//Time to start building the file to go out.

$total_report = array();
foreach($reports_in_db as $key)
{
    $total_report [$key->line_number] = $key;                       
}
// get subtitles/abstract
$sql = "SELECT line_number, field_text FROM subtitle_abstract_summary WHERE report_key = '" . $report_key . "'";            
$abs_sums = $wpdb->get_results ($sql);
//now for a series of conditional things
if (empty($abs_sums))
{
    //echo "subtitles/abstracts"
}
else
{
    foreach ($abs_sums as $key)
    {
        $total_report [$key->line_number] = $key;
    }
}
```

So what I expected to happen, is to create an array where the main data rows have the subtitles rows interspersed. What *actually* happens is that $total_report has all the main data rows, followed by all the subtitles rows. When I print_r the array, they're not in the order I expect.

for example, if the data rows are row 1-200, and the subtitle rows are 121, 161, and 181, this code produces an array that has elements 1-120, 122-160, 162-180, then 121,161 and 181 in that order.

Currently, the elements are WPDB objects. If possible, I'd like to be able to just get them in the right order. If there's also a simple way to just sort by the element number, that's okay too.

I've tried doing sort() on $total_report- but that sorted by the alphabetical value of the first field of the object..

I'm honestly just puzzled why the array doesn't have the elements in the order I thought they'd be in.

Thanks

Comment: Array elements have the order they have been inserted in, simple as that. _"I've tried doing sort() on $total_report- but that sorted by the alphabetical value of the first field of the object"_ - well if you simply want them sorted by key(?), then use the appropriate sort function for that ... http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Thank you- this really does help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ksort()` to sort array by keys. And `SORT_NUMERIC` flag so it would sort it as numbers:

```
<?php
   ...
   ksort($total_report,SORT_NUMERIC);
   ...
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! ksort totally worked. That actually solved one of the major (well it seemed major) remaining problems of this project.